# UIImageViews are repeating in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a cell that holds an UIScrollView which will have a few UIImageViews which will hold images downloaded from Parse.

This works great when it loads the first 5 in my tableview, but after the fifth, more and more UIImageViews are stacked over one another.

I believe that problem lies when I use the:

```
cell.scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
```

This adds and keeps adding new UIImageViews in the scrollView.

I've been trying different things to remove the UIImageViews but I can't seem to implement it correctly.

I'm back to square one but now I know what is causing the problem.

This is how I'm downloading my images from Parse:

```
photoQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        for object in objects!{

            var arrayFile = [PFFile]() // hold both image into temp array

            if object.objectForKey("imageOne") != nil {
                self.resultsHasImageOneFile.append(object.objectForKey("imageOne") as! PFFile)
                arrayFile.append(object.objectForKey("imageOne") as! PFFile)
            }

            if object.objectForKey("imageTwo") != nil {
                self.resultsHasImageTwoFile.append(object.objectForKey("imageTwo") as! PFFile)

                arrayFile.append(object.objectForKey("imageTwo") as! PFFile)
            }
            // will add imageThree
            // will add imageFour
            // will add imageFive

            self.masterImageArray.append(arrayFile)//add temp array into Master Image array
            self.resultsTable.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

this is how i'm adding my UIImageViews into my scrollView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // configure cell....

    var imageArray = masterArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageScrollView.tag = indexPath.row // do something with this?????

    for var i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++ {

        var myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

        myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
        myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
        myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition

        imageArray[i].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            myImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        }

        cell.imageScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)

        xPosition = imageWidth
        scrollViewContentSize += imageWidth

        cell.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight)

        cell.imageScrollView.tag = indexPath.row // do something with this?????
    }
}
```

I've tried to remove what's inside the cell content with the following but it says it has found nil, which crashes.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell = FriendsFeedTableViewCell()
    cell.imageScrollView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

in my FriendsFeedTableViewCell class, I only have a label, and a UIScrollView which is named

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!
```

How can I properly remove the already created UIImageViews?

Comment: Are you trying to download images from parse then show it into a tableview

Comment: They are already downloaded. I have the NSData saved in a master array. at IndexPath, it creates the UIImageViews for the NSData which they do. Since I have a transparency (using PNG) I can see the other UIImageViews in other cells. They are being created over and over on top of each other.

Comment: can you post a picture of that tableview

Comment: Why are you initializing a new cell in your didEndDisplayingCell method? can you show your complete code so that we find the issue?

Comment: and also show FriendsFeedTableViewCell class

Comment: @Lamar I posted a pic

Comment: @Shoaib I don't have much in FriendsFeedTableViewCell class incept an outlet for my basic outlets for label and scrollView

Comment: I believed you are doing too much, you should completely download the images then put into an array and i will get easier when you want to deal with the scrollView

Answer (score 0):

I believed that you are doing too much work by accessing Parse Twice, you should download every single images once and insert them into a single array of objects. Example :

```
    var photoQuery = PFQuery(className: "")
photoQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil
    {
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
        {
            for singleObject in objects
            {
                var ImageDataToDownload = singleObject["images"] as! PFFile
                ImageDataToDownload.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (dataToget:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil
                    {
                        if let  image = UIImage(data: dataToget!) {
                                // pass this image to  your array 
                                // reload tableview
                        }
                    }
                })
             }}}}
```

**then in cellForRowAtIndexPath()**

```
    cell.imageView.image = arrayFromQuery[indexPath.row]
  then you take care of your scrollview inside that cell
```

Comment: You are so right. It makes total sense. I thought it would be a little faster since it's just holding NSData and not images but I'm just confusing myself way to much. I'm going to re-write half of my app so far. I'll get back in like 2-3 days.

Comment: yeah no problem just let me know if anything